# Webmethods in base page, works in one inherited page, not but in a second

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, pagemethods

I am trying to move my common `PageMethods` to a `MyBasePage` in which two `.aspx` pages will inherit.

On `page1.aspx`,  I can call the `PageMethods.SetFormID("abc")` fine.

However, on `page2.aspx`, I get 
        'PageMethods is undefined' 
error, when trying to access the same method `PageMethods.SetFormID("def");`

Here is my pseudocode:

1. `MyBasePage` inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`, and includes the `WebMethodAttribute`, the method is both static and public.

   ```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void SetFormID(string formID)
    {
       //save formID as a session variable;
    }
   ```
2. Both pages inherit from `MyBasePage`

   ```
   public partial class Page1 : MyBasePage

   public partial class Page2 : MyBasePage
   ```
3. Both pages include a `ScriptManger` line with `EnablePageMethods="true"`

   ```
   < asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>
   ```
4. From the javascript on each page, I call

   ```
   PageMethods.SetFormID(id);
   ```
5. I transition to `Page2.aspx`, by calling either:

   ```
   window.open("Page2.aspx");
    -or-
   window.location("Page2.aspx");
   ```

Thus, I must have done something wrong with `Page2.aspx`, so I tried saving `Page1.aspx` as `Page2.aspx` (thus, both pages would have identical code, except the class name).  Page 1 works as before, but Page 2 fails with `PageMethods is undefined`.

I then tried to set Page2 as the startPage in VS, and have it call Page1.  Page 2 can now call the PageMethods fine, but Page1 will fail.

Anyone have any ideas on what is happening here?  Should I be able to call `PageMethods` defined in my baseClass from any page derived from it?  Maybe it has something to do with how the page is transitioned?

PS: it is a VS2012, .NET4 project

Comment: Just made a new ASP.NET project to reproduce what you said. Cannot reproduce even with  `window.location` changing the page. Try I new project I think you are missing something litle.

Comment: I created a new project, and copied over the pages to the new project, and it works fine.